# How to find the number of positive and negative numbers are there on an input field?

Tags: javascript

My question is there are 3 input text field and a button, whatever the user enters and press the button, an alert should say how many negative numbers and how many positive numbers are on the text field?

Comment: what are the input fields and buttons called? are you using straight javascript or allowed to use jquery, etc? have you tried any code to solve this yet? if so, let us see what you've tried so far...

Comment: I think you should do your own homework.  ;-)

Comment: @BJSafdie I have done it before I posted the question and wanted to know if the way I did it was correct or not but thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnkhrd31/1/) The code is explained as below.

If you want to enter a number in each of the text field and click the button which tells the number of positive and negative numbered entered then here is your code,

You HTML code,

```
<input id="one" type="text"/>
<input id="two" type="text"/>
<input id="three" type="text"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check();" value="check">
```

Now you can write  the script as follows,

```
function check(){

    //Converting the values to integer
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("two").value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("three").value);

    //Initializing the positive and negative count to 0 
    var posCount = 0;
    var negCount = 0;

    //Incrementing postive and negative count depending whether it is      positive or negative
    if(x>=0){
        posCount++;
    }else{
        negCount++;
    }
    if(y>=0){
        posCount++;
    }else{
        negCount++;
    }
    if(z>=0){
        posCount++;
    }else{
        negCount++;
    }
    alert("Positive numbers: "+posCount);
    alert("Negative numbers: "+negCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I did it in a different way but it is similar